# Error al ejecutar programa extensión .sqr

Tags: oracle

Ejecutando un programa con extensión .sqr
Un SQR odbc para ser más específico (SQR 83) se me presenta el siguiente mensaje de error:
(SQR 5528) ODBC dbftch error 0 in cursor 3: 
 [DataDirect][ODBC 20101 driver]157
(SQR 5528) ODBC dbftch error 0 in cursor 3: 
 [DataDirect][ODBC 20101 driver]1906072
(SQR 5528) ODBC dbftch error 0 in cursor 3: 
 [DataDirect][ODBC 20101 driver]1906072
(SQR 5528) ODBC dbftch error 0 in cursor 3: 
 [DataDirect][ODBC 20101 driver]157

Error on line 78:
(SQR 3725) Bad return fetching row from database.

Agradezco si a alguien  le ha sucedido a tiene alguna idea de a que se deba.

Comment: el error esta en tu query no en el odbc hay dice claramante cursor!

Comment: He validado el mismo query, realizando la consulta en un cliente sql y no da problemas. Se ejecuta correctamente.

Comment: puedes validar haciendo una prueba con querys ultra basicas e ir subiendo a ver que caracteres no son aceptables!

Comment: El gran problema está en que esto se da en un ambiente al que no tengo acceso. Y como es típico..  En ambientes de desarrollo no sucede y no se replica...